# How to calculate date difference in SQL

Tags: sql

In Vertica, I've got this table which shows me buyers who returned items:

```
buyer_id         event_name  event_value
684039235358     purchase    2022-08-23
684039235358     return      2022-10-23
283038488486     purchase    2022-10-02
283038488486     return      2022-11-16
```

How can I query this data so that I will have the difference in days for each buyer between purchase and return?

```
buyer_id           difference_in_days
684039235358       21
283038488486       35
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Many products have their own date/time functions.)

Comment: and which database are you using?

Comment: What's the expected result if a buyer has a purchase with no return? And if a buyer has several purchases?

Comment: your first purchase, will be in 2023 and the return is 2022

Comment: Thanks for the comments, jarlh and nbk. I edited the question with the information I have at hand. 

In this table, every buyer_id is a buyer that returned an item. 

I edited the dates in the sample data as well, even though I would not know they matter so much.

Comment: https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Date-Time/DATEDIFF.htm

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select
    buyer_id, datediff(day, t1.event_value, t2.event_value)
from yourtable t1
join yourtable t2 on
      t2.buyer_id = t1.buyer_id 
  and t2.event_name = 'return'
where
  t1.event_name = 'purchase'
```